# jQuery animating div switcher for corresponding list-item

Tags: jquery

I'm currently learning jquery and have run into a snag. I'm working on building a page with two sections. One is an unordered list of food types. The other is a set of divs with each displaying different types of beer that would complement each of the food types. Each list-item and its corresponding div share the same class. All of the divs are positioned out of view to start.

What I want to accomplish is that onclick of each list-item, whatever div that is in view animates out of view, and then the corresponding div of the clicked list-item animates into view.

I got this working, but then for some reason, it stopped working. I do not know if this has something to do with my code or if there is a better way to go about accomplishing this project.

```
    $(function(){
       $('.beer_container > div.default').css('top', '0');
       $('ul.food_items li').click(function(){
        var theClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var $theBeer = $('div.beer_container > div[class="+ theClass +"]');
        var $oldBeer = $('div.beer_container > div:not([class="+ theClass +"])');

          $oldBeer.animate(
           {'top': '-420'}, 
            'slow', function(){
          $theBeer.animate(
           {'top': '0'}, 'slow');
           });
         });

      });




        <div class="left food_container">
          <ul class="food_items">
            <li class="lighter_foods">Lighter Foods</li>
            <li class="classic_burger">Classic Burger</li>
            <li class="strong_spicy">Strong &amp; Spicy</li>
            <li class="rich_hearty">Rich &amp; Hearty</li>
            <li class="smoked">Smoked Meats</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right beer_container">
          <div class="default">
            This is the intro page. What are you eating?
          </div>
          <div class="lighter_foods">
            Blonde Ale, Hefeweizen, Wheat Ale, Witbier, Pilsener
          </div>
          <div class="classic_burger">
            Pale Ale, Amber/Red Ale, Amber Lager
          </div>
          <div class="strong_spicy">
            IPA, Amber/Red Ale, Abbey Tripel, Sweet or Oatmeal Stout, Oktoberfest/Maerzen, Pale Bock
          </div>
          <div class="rich_hearty">
            Bitter, Scotch Ale, Brown Ale, Abbey Dubbel, Old or Strong Ale, Porter, Dry Stout, Dunkelweizen, Weizenbock, Doppelbock, Dark Lager
          </div>
          <div class="smoked">
            Double/Imperial IPA, Brown Ale, Abbey Dubbel, Porter, Imperial Stout
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some single quotes became double quotes.

```
var $theBeer = $('div.beer_container > div[class=' + theClass + ']');
var $oldBeer = $('div.beer_container > div:not([class=' + theClass + '])');
```

I'm not endorsing that method of targeting, but you definitely don't want to be looking for div with the class "+ theClass +"

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel like such a noob!